# Manipulating array to pass to a different method and then class

Tags: java, arrays

If I have an array that gets updated as I run a program (say I ask the player for 5 numbers), call is `ClassA` and then want to save it using a different class, call it `ClassB` that imports the data from `ClassA`, how would I do this?

I am able to create a global variable and pass that information to `ClassB` but how would I pass a method that takes an argument from a different method to this file?

Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
class quiz
{
   --- other code irrelavent to question ---

   public static int[] scorearrayp1()
   {
      int[] scorep1 = new int[4]; // this creates the array that gets filled later
      return new int[4];
   }

   public static void askQ(scorep1)
   {
      JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Some numbers");
      // this method then fills the array depending on user input
      // it is the values from here that I wish to save in classB
   }

   public static int[] passArray(int[] scorep1)
   {
      return scorep1; // this is from class A and takes the value from a method before
   }
```

And this is the class I want to send this array to:

```
class saveScores
{
    public static void main(String[] params) throws IOException 
    {
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("scores.txt"));

        finalproject data = new finalproject();
        int[] scores = data.passArray(int[] scorep1);
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
        {
           outputStream.println(scores[i]);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

At the moment I'm being thrown two errors

```
error:'.class' expected
int[] scores = data.passArray(int[] scorep1);
                                    ^
error:';' expected
int[] scores = data.passArray(int[] scorep1);
                                           ^
```

I had the idea to change `passArray(int[] scorep1)` to `passArray(scorep1)` but then it just tells me that the symbol cannot be found.

Comment: `passArray(scorep1)` is correct, but if you want to pass an array to that method, you must declare that array first.

Comment: your functions in quiz are all static, means class method. so you will have to access them using quiz.scorearrayp1(), quiz.askQ(), quiz.passArray(). secondly, you're not storing your array anywhere in quiz. And where does finalproject class comes from? I suggest you read a little bit about data encapsulations. It will help you on archiving what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
int[] scores = data.passArray(int[] scorep1);
```

to

```
int[] scores = data.passArray(scorep1);
```

But still you will need to declare `scorep1`, for example like:

```
int[] scorep1 = new int[]{1, 0, 0}
```

According to your edited question (and if I understand right), your code should look like the following:

```
int[] scores = quiz.passArray(quiz.scorearrayp1());
```

Anyway, please keep in mind that class names should always be uppercase.

Comment: This is where the nature of this array comes into play. The array is initialized in `ClassA` and will contain numbers that the user has input after compiling and running `ClassA`. If I declare score1 like you have said it will always print out `1 0 0` to the txt document and I don't want that. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: So where does scorep1 come from? It's not in your code. Anyway your code to pass it to the method is incorrect.

Comment: I have editted the first part of my code to show where the array actually comes from. I want to pass what that contains to `classB`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 class quiz{
  int[] scorep1 = null;
 public quiz()
   {
   scorep1 = new int[4]; // this creates the array that gets filled later
  }

 public static int[] askQ()
  {
   JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Some numbers");
   // here call fills the array depending on user input
  }
```

And do this:

```
  int[] somearray = quiz.askQ();
  int[] scores = data.passArray(somearray);
```

You should create an array `somearray`  like above to pass at the method `data.passArray(somearray);`

Comment: Doesn't this just create an array that has nothing stored in it? When I change the code to this I get a txt document with `0 0 0 0` saved if I create an array of size 4

Comment: @Overclock you can add elements like above

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to create an array with random elements, rather I want the elements that the user themself has entered in `classA`.

Comment: @Overclock do you mean in class quiz

Comment: Yes I meant class quiz, sorry